# What is the matter with the babies Evan's mother had before?

Tags: the-butterfly-effect

During the movie "The Butterfly Effect" Evan's mother said she have had babies before, but they all died. He was "the miracle" baby.

What does this mean?

Why did the other babies die? Have they gone through the same thing as Evan?

Answer (score 13):

First of all, I'd agree with *Will*'s answer that with *"miracle baby"* she merely meant that he was a miracle to her in that he was the first of her pregnancies that did not die before birth. But there is in fact much more to this and the movie indeed indicates that the other babies had the same "abilities" as Evan and went through the same hassle as him.

The Director's Cut of the movie features a completely different ending than the theatrical version (which actually blew me away when I first heard about it), as also discussed in [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/8256/49) to a related question. In the psychatric hosptital, instead of watching the video of his first meeting with *Caley*, *Evan* watches the video of his own birth and he travels back into his own past as unborn baby inside the womb of his mother. There he decides to finally put an end to all this by strangling himself with his own umbilical cord.

This (together with the voice over of his mother telling about the other dead babies) in fact strongly indicates that **in different timelines all her previous babies actually grew up and got trapped in exactly this same circle of worsening things by trying to "correct" them, ultimately deciding to never get born at all**. It also makes sense for all of them to have *Evan*'s abilities when you consider that **he inherited them from his father**, so they seem to be somehow genetical, just that his father maneuvered himself into a situtation where he could not prevent all this from happening.

Comment: Very good answer!I also think that the earlier babies went through the same thing. And since the babies kept dying Evan's father knew what was happening. That's why he said "it's the only way to end it" when he tries to strangle Evan. No matter what, excellent movie!

Answer (score 0):

"Miracle baby" means the mother gives birth despite having a medical condition that normally makes pregnancy difficult or impossible, or that prevents successfully carrying a baby to term.  I did not see anything in the movie to indicate that her previous children went through the same thing as Evan, with the time travel and the retroactive suicide.

Answer (score 0):

That means Evan's mother continues to give fourth baby when she narrates "Before you were born i was pregnant 3 times" but originally, it was 2 times.She is saying it to her 4th baby.