# Who was the 2nd family holding their new born baby in the lawn?

Tags: the-butterfly-effect

In the movie, The Butterfly Effect, there are 4 multiple endings as mentioned in [What was the original ending and why was it changed?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8242/what-was-the-original-ending-and-why-was-it-changed)

In the above video, who was this family at [8.15](https://youtu.be/NeV0MvU1Uhs?t=497)?

Was it the baby which was saved from the blast that had happened earlier? Or was it Evan's mom who was having a normal baby after 3 still-births?

Comment: Blocked in the US on copyright grounds.  :(

Answer (score 3):

After finding the video in another thread (I can't view the one in this thread as my country has blocked it on copyright grounds) I'm taking a guess that the mother is a redhead and the father has wavy dark hair?  If so, the mother is clearly the same actress playing Ashton Kutcher's mom in the scene where Kutcher strangles himself.  It can only be assumed that the scene in question is, indeed, Kutcher's mom having a normal child which appears to be a girl (I'd assume so that it's clear the child is *not* Kutcher's character).